# How do I remove the contents from a file?

Tags: java, file

How do I remove the content added to a file in append mode. This file contains large amount of records prior to the appended data.

How do I remove the jsonObject3 and jsonObject4 from this file? Please refer the code below

```
public class MainDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, 
                      ClassNotFoundException, IOException {


    String FileSeparator=System.getProperty("file.separator");
    Path p=Paths.get("Dummy\\Downloads\\Test\\2018-12-28\\D");

    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject();  
    jsonObject1.put("id",1);
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();  
    jsonObject2.put("id",2);
    JSONObject jsonObject3 = new JSONObject();  
    jsonObject3.put("id",3);

    JSONObject jsonObject4 = new JSONObject();  
    jsonObject4.put("id",4);

    List<JSONObject> al=new ArrayList<>();

    al.add(jsonObject1);
    al.add(jsonObject2);
    al.add(jsonObject3);
    al.add(jsonObject4);

    for(JSONObject jsonObject:al) {
        String json=jsonObject.toString();      
        Files.write(
                Paths.get(p+FileSeparator+"Dummy.json"), 
                json.getBytes(), 
                StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

    }
    al.clear();
          // How do I remove the jsonObject3 and jsonObject4 from Dummy.json file

}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier (and infinitely faster) to **not** write `jsonObject3` *or* `jsonObject4` to the file in the first place? `for (JSONObject jsonObject : al.subList(0, 2)) {`

Comment: My requirement is like that. I may need to remove all four also.

Comment: How large is your file? Does it fit in your RAM? If so, you can read content to list of strings, filter it (by streams for example) and then overwrite existing file.

Comment: You can truncate the file using RandomAccessFile setLength. You need to know the length you want to make the file.

Comment: The only sensible solution would seem to be to rewrite the file then replace the original. You're really going to struggle to truncate the file to the right length?

Comment: Don't do this - `Paths.get(p+FileSeparator+"Dummy.json")`. There are perfectly good methods for this - `p.resolve("Dummy.json")` or `Paths.get(p, "Dummy.json")`. Your homebrew nonsense is only going to cause you problems.

Comment: Also, opening a new stream for each object isn't the best of ideas.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey I have accessed the channel out of RandomAccessFile to truncate and to get the position of the file I am operating on.

Answer (score -1):

In this case you should append the objects with the help of a separator string or a symbol like '$' etc and then you can read the file and then store the read string in a string variable.
Then you will get the objects in an array using string.split(separatorString).
Then remove the element which you want and rewrite the data in the file in overwrite mode from the array.

Comment: It's JSON - if there are multiple objects concatted in the file then there already is a perfectly good separator. Your suggestion is essentilly "read the file into memory, split it to an array in memory, write the file out again" - this solution is not only horribly slow but will not work for files that are remotely large.